# Can't select parts of model in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have a model in Forge Viewer that has very inconsistent mouse selection behaviour.

1. All parts are always highlighted on mouse over.
2. A certain subset of the parts cannot be selected by mouse click. It's as if they are invisible to the click as parts occluded by them will be selected instead.
3. Parts that cannot be selected can become selectable if the scene is panned or rotated.
4. If the scene is reloaded the subset of unselectable parts usually changes.
5. If I implement my own click check with viewer.clientToWorld it also doesn't register a hit on the unselectable parts.

Hiding or isolation is not on when this happens.
This has so far never happened on any other model. Is there something I can check about this certain model or is this just a problem with the viewer?

Edit: Added some bounding box pics.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check bounding boxes of the parts that can't be selected, e.g., using something like [this](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-viewer-utils/blob/develop/src/Utilities.js#L440-L448)? I'm wondering if the bboxes are somehow off, making the ray casting logic ignore them.

Comment: You're right, they are off. I added a picture of two examples. The column in the front has an odd shaped box and the one in the back only has a vertical plane.

Comment: Didn't notice it earlier but all the rectangle bases also have really wonky bounding boxes.

Comment: In that case this seems to be an issue with IFC (I assume this is IFC, right?) to SVF. If you could share the model with us via forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com, we would pass the info along to the translation team.

Comment: Yup, IFC. Thanks, I'll send it over.